# Citing equations in ieee (biblatex+biber), same source but in different pages

Tags: biblatex, biber

Let's say that in some book there is a equation 1.2 in page 1 and some other equation 3.6 in page 120.

I would like that my output looked like this:

bla bla [1, eq. 1.2]
...
bla bla [2, eq. 3.6]

References:

[1] ....., p. 1

[2] ....., p. 120

I know I can add "eq. X" using square brackets in the citation command, that's not the deal. The thing is, I want to refer to the same source, I just want to change the page (in ieee citation you have to specify this at the end of the reference as I just showed), is there some way to add something like a postnote but not intext, but in the reference?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Given that you're citing two different passages out of one and the same publication, why would you *not* want to use the same main number in both citation call-outs?

Comment: Our professor told us that in case we cite two different equations from the same source, we could use the same passage if both equations were in the same section. Otherwise we would had to cite them as two different passages.

Comment: Are you sure you understood the requirement correctly? With postnotes in the text you can differentiate the two passages easily, e.g., _bla bla [1, p.1 eq. 1.2] ... bla bla [1, p. 120 eq. 3.6]_. However, if you really want this then you can just duplicate the reference in your `.bib` file with two different cite keys and a different `note = {p. x}` field in each.